# Split file on every second line and format the results as a table

Tags: php, html

I have a `.txt` file where each line contains a number value.

The first line is a student's score on a test. The second line is the highest possible score for that test.

I'm tasked with converting this content to an html table with these requirements:

- each row in the table must contain the columns of row index, score, possible score, percentage in that order
- the last row of the table should total the values like Student score= 761 Possible= 850 Percentage= 90%

The .txt file is called scores.txt and below are the grades.

```
89
100
67
75
89
90
57
65
34
40
62
70
49
55
80
95
45
60
189
200
```

Below is what it should look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <body>

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Index</th>
        <th>Student Score</th>
        <th>Possible Score</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
      <tr>

      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>89</td>
        <td>100</td>
        <td>89%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>67</td>
        <td>75</td>
        <td>89%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>89</td>
        <td>90</td>
        <td>99%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>57</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>88%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>85%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>70</td>
        <td>89%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>49</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>89%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>80 </td>
        <td>95</td>
        <td>84%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>60</td>
        <td>75%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>189</td>
        <td>200</td>
        <td>95%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Total</td>
        <td>761</td>
        <td>850</td>
        <td>90%</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>

</html>
```

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head><title>Grades Results</title></head>

<body>

<html>
<body>
<?
    if(!file_exists("scores.txt"))
    {
        echo "The file from above cannot be found!";
        exit;
    }
    
    $fp = fopen("scores.txt", "r");
    
    if(!$fp)
    {
        echo "Somehow the file cannot be opened! :)";
        exit;
    }
    echo "<table border = 4>";
    $counter = 1;
    while(!feof($fp))
    {
        $zeile = fgets($fp);
        echo "<tr><td>$counter</td>";
        echo "<td>$zeile</td>";
        $counter++;
    }
        echo "</table>";
    fclose($fp)
    
?>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATE:
I rewrote my code and it is still not working, I even added list areas to add and it is confusing me even more.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head><title>Grades Results</title></head>

<body>

<html>
<table>
<tr>
</tr>
<table>   
    <?php
        $file = fopen("scores.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
        while (!feof($file)){   
            $data = fgets($file); 
            list($studentscore, $possiblescore, $percentage) = explode("|", $data);
    ?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?=$studentscore ?></td>
        <td><?=$possiblescore ?></td>
        <td><?=$percentage ?></td>
        ...
    </tr>
    <?php
        }
        fclose($failas);
   ?>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's your actual question? What output _do_ you get and how does that differ from what you expect?

Comment: One thing I notice is that your first echo `echo "<tr><td>$counter</td>";` opens a `tr` tag but none of your later code ever closes that tag.

Comment: @WesleySmith My actual question is how to get the output of the given HTML code. My current code just compiles to 2 rows and no labels are seen.

Comment: You should echo out the elements that you so far haven't. If you wrote the code so far, you should be able to add in the missing pieces without much trouble. It sounds like you are asking us to write it for you. that's not what SO is for and it wont help you in your studies. On the other hand, if you have a specific question about a part of this that you're having trouble with, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Please show your changes

Comment: Updated up top @WesleySmith

Comment: If your .txt file is as you've shown (ie with ONLY grades in it, one on each line), how do you know what the "Possible Score" is? there's a "200" in the file so presumably the "Possible score" is that or above?? Are you required to use specific functions for this?

Comment: The 200 is the possible score you can get on the assignment , so it is taking the 189 and dividing by 200 to get a 95%, basic math. I just do not get on how to get the math portions to add up and how to format my numbers properly so they are in their own categories.  Strictly online schooling makes this subject a bit harder to learn.

Comment: Can you please provide the actual content of "scores.txt"? In your question you say `The .txt file is called scores.txt and below are the grades.` That makes it sound like the section below it is the content from "scores.txt" and it contains only grades (presumably one per line) but your last comment casts doubt on that

Comment: What was given to me were the scores.txt which contain the grades (the numbers).

Comment: So each line in the file contains just one grade value and thats it, correct? If so, where do you get the "Possible Score" of 200 from? Is that a constant value or does it come from this file also?

Comment: Also, when you say " how to format my numbers properly so they are in their own categories", do you mean how can I output the values so that each row in the table contains the columns of row index, score, possible score, percentage in that order?

Comment: Also, are you meant to sort the results in order of grade at all? Or just print them in the order they appear in the file?

Comment: So for the scores.txt it says "The file you will use is posted in a single column with alternating values. The first value is the first student score. The
second value is the possible score for that first test. The third value is the second student score and the fourth value is
the possible score for that second test. The alternating data points continue for the entire file." And yes, Index, student score, possible score, and percentage in that order.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes a lot more sense. Gimme a min to help, meanwhile, please see my last question about sorting

Comment: Yes, they do need to be added up! They will add up at the bottom of the page. So it would be 
total = 
Student score=  761
Possible= 850
Percentage= 90%
Thank you for helping me out!

Comment: Note, ive updated your question tittle and description to better convey the problem. Feel free to re-edit if I didnt describe something correctly

Comment: Are you using php7?

Comment: I am using PHP from Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will do what you need [as seen in this example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8ab2235fadccc96a85627d3e5a6c0de49ff6ff56).

NOTE: Now that we've done your homework for you, your new assignment is to read all of the comments in the code below and then read the documentation for all the functions and language constructs used so that you will understand *how* this does what you need and become a better programmer.:

Reading list:

- [file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)
- [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count)
- [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk)
- [round](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)
- [type casting.... ie (int)](https://www.greycampus.com/codelabs/php/type-casting)
- [modulo](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-modulo-operator-in-php--cms-32393)
- [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)
- [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)
- [divide by zero error](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php)

PHP Code:

```
<?php

// get an array of all of the lines contained in the src file
if (!$lines = file('scores.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)) {
    die('Unable to open file!'); // I'd do something better with this personally...
}
// count of all lines should be an even number, if not, something is wrong with the file...
if(count($lines) % 2 !== 0){
    die('File contains an odd number of lines!'); // I'd do something better with this personally...
}

// split that array into an array of arrays where each inner array contains 2 values/lines
// the first value in each array will be a student's score, the second will be the highest possible score for that test
$tests = array_chunk ($lines,2);

// loop over the tests array and process each assigning the results to a new array
$rows = [];
$totalScored = 0;
$totalPossible = 0;
foreach ($tests as $index => $test) {

    $score          = (int)$test[0];
    $possibleScore  = (int)$test[1];
    $percentage     = $score <= 0 ? '0' : ($score / $possibleScore) * 100; // NOTE that we check for 0 here to avoid "divide by 0" errors!
    $percentage     = round($percentage).'%';
    $totalScored   += $score;
    $totalPossible += $possibleScore;

    $rows[]= [$index+1, $score, $possibleScore, $percentage];
}
// now add our totals row
$totalPercentage     = $totalScored <= 0 ? '0' : ($totalScored / $totalPossible) * 100;
$totalPercentage     = round($totalPercentage).'%';
$rows[]= ['Total', $totalScored, $totalPossible, $totalPercentage];

// lets keep the html as clean as possible by converting all the elements of the array 
// we could have done this in the above foreach loop, but I'd prefer to keep that array with just the values
// in case we need them for anything else later.
$tableRows = array_map(
    static function($row) {
        return '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $row).'</td></tr>';
    },
    $rows
);

// finally, turn that array of strings into one long string of html. 
$tableRowString = implode(PHP_EOL, $tableRows);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Grades Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Index</th>
        <th>Student Score</th>
        <th>Possible Score</th>
        <th>Percentage</th>
    <tr>
    <?= $tableRowString ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Modified version to work with dinosaur PHP versions...

[Proof it works on php 5.1.5](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c0c3f7ae1db1f9d0941cdf0df602d570d77d7726)

```
<?php

// get an array of all of the lines contained in the src file
if (!$lines = file('scores.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)) {
    die('Unable to open file!'); // I'd do something better with this personally...
}

// count of all lines should be an even number, if not, something is wrong with the file...
if(count($lines) % 2 !== 0){
    die('File contains an odd number of lines!'); // I'd do something better with this personally...
}

// split that array into an array of arrays where each inner array contains 2 values/lines
// the first value in each array will be a student's score, the second will be the highest possible score for that test
$tests = array_chunk ($lines,2);

// loop over the tests array and process each assigning the results to a new array
$rows = array();
$totalScored = 0;
$totalPossible = 0;
foreach ($tests as $index => $test) {
    
    $score          = (int)$test[0];
    $possibleScore  = (int)$test[1];
    $percentage     = $score <= 0 ? '0' : ($score / $possibleScore) * 100; // NOTE that we check for 0 here to avoid "divide by 0" errors!
    $percentage     = round($percentage).'%';
    $totalScored   += $score;
    $totalPossible += $possibleScore;

    $rows[]= array($index+1, $score, $possibleScore, $percentage);
}
// now add our totals row
$totalPercentage     = $totalScored <= 0 ? '0' : ($totalScored / $totalPossible) * 100;
$totalPercentage     = round($totalPercentage).'%';
$rows[]= array('Total', $totalScored, $totalPossible, $totalPercentage);

// lets keep the html as clean as possible by converting all the elements of the array 
// we could have done this in the above foreach loop, but I'd prefer to keep that array with just the values
// in case we need them for anything else later.

function callback($row) {
        return '<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>', $row).'</td></tr>';
};
$tableRows = array_map('callback', $rows);

// finally, turn that array of strings into one long string of html. 
$tableRowString = implode("\n", $tableRows);


echo $tableRowString;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222572/discussion-on-answer-by-wesley-smith-split-file-on-every-second-line-and-format).